# Poisson Process and the gambler's ruin problem

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk, poisson-process

The following problem is a variation from one of Ross's Stochastic Methods textbook problems: team 1 and 2 are playing a match. The teams score points according to independent Poisson processes with rates 4 and 1, respectively. The match ends when one of the teams scores 5 more points than the other. Find the probability that team 1 wins.

I have approached the problem as follows:

$$P(N_1\ge N_2+5)=P(N_1-N_2\ge 5)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} P(N_1=i+5,N_2=i)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} P(N_1=i+5)P(N_2=i)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} e^{-4}\frac{4^{i+5}}{(i+5)!}e^{-1}\frac{1^{i}}{i!}=e^{-5}4^{5}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{4^{i}}{i!(i+5)!}$$

Where $N_1,N_2$ are the random variables representing the scores of team 1 and team 2, respectively. Calculating this with Maplesoft gives me a probability of $0.1088$.

However, if I use the gambler's ruin problem, where a gambler starts with 5 points, wins if it gets to 10 points and losses if it goes to 0 points, with the probability of team one winning one point equal to $\frac{4}{5}$ and losing one point equal to $\frac{1}{5}$, the probability of team one winning is $$\frac{1-(1/4)^5}{1-(1/4)^{10}}\approx1$$

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: The main issue is that calculating $P(N_1\ge N_2+5)$ has nothing to do with your problem.  Your problem has a two sided *stopping rule* but $P(N_1\ge N_2+5)$ does not involve any such thing.  Another issue is you wrote $P(N_1-N_2\ge 5)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} P(N_1=i+5,N_2=i)$ but the RHS  $=P(N_1-N_2= 5) $ and your calculation ignores $P(N_1-N_2\gt 5) $.  Also Poisson processes would be given by $N_1(t)$ and $N_2(t)$ but you do have a $t$ in there which is another issue.  Consider supplementing with *Stochastic Processes* as it does a better job teaching the theory than most of Ross's books.

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand your first comment: I am allowing for example $N_1=12$ and  $N_2=4$, which is wrong since the match would stop when the point difference is 5. But I do not understand your second comment. If I look at the infinitely many possible results of the match, all of them with exactly 5 point difference, wouldn't that be reflected in $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} P(N_1=i+5,N_2=i)$ ?

I do not like Ross's book, particularly, the exercises at the end of each chapter. You mention the book Stochastic Processes. Would you please let me know the author?

Thanks

Comment: *" If I look at the infinitely many possible results of the match, all of them with exactly 5 point difference"*  ... but that is what an expression like $P(N_1-N_2= 5)$ would try to calculate yet you wrote  $P(N_1-N_2\ge 5)$, and $P(N_1-N_2\ge 5)\gt P(N_1-N_2= 5)$ so which is it?  The book is called *Stochastic Processes* by Ross-- I managed to find a 1st edition for $<\$ 10$ a few years back.  In general the newer editions don't add much, e.g. 12th edition of *Introduction to Probability Models*!? I have an earlier [but not 1st] edition of said book and thought it was dreadful.

Comment: Thank you, again, although I cannot help sensing a certain level of unnecessary hostility in your response. But maybe it is just me. What I was asking is why the following solution to the problem is incorrect, and I know it is incorrect:

$$P(N_1= N_2+5)=P(N_1-N_2= 5)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} P(N_1=i+5,N_2=i)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} P(N_1=i+5)P(N_2=i)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} e^{-4}\frac{4^{i+5}}{(i+5)!}e^{-1}\frac{1^{i}}{i!}=e^{-5}4^{5}\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{4^{i}}{i!(i+5)!}$$

Comment: As I originally remarked the main issue is your expression does not involve the required two sided stopping rule so it cannot be correct.  There was no hostility intended and I even gave tips on getting better/complementary materials from Ross on the cheap, so your hostility accusation is quite remarkable.  I will not be engaging with you further.

Comment: oh, and that is not hostile at all, I guess. I do not understand why you are so eager to initially participate in helping when in reality you just made me waste a lot of precious time. Anyways, I guess that is one of the risks of anonymity... Have a wonderful life.